# newgrp and gpasswd versions

Tags: debian, package-management, version

Spinning a clean docker image. I have these two binaries with an SUID bit.

```
root@08b5da082a90:/# find / -perm -u=s -ls 2> /dev/null
    ...
    32021     44 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root        44440 Jul 27  2018 /usr/bin/newgrp
    31977     84 -rwsr-xr-x   1 root     root        84016 Jul 27  2018 /usr/bin/gpasswd
    ...
```

I am trying to get their versions in the container but can't find a method to do it, however I can see on my host machine that these binaries are from the `shadow-utils {version}` package as it is mentioned in the bottom of their manpages.

I am trying to get at least see what version of `shadow-utils` are those two binaries from.

I have tried looking for the `shadow-utils` package in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` but nothing shows up after grepping, probably because a fresh `debian` distro hasn't got it installed.

How do I see what I'm looking for, without installing the `man` command within the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
man shadow
```

should be able to tell you at the very bottom of the page, mine tells :

> SHADOW(3)  Library Calls  SHADOW(3) NAME
>  shadow, getspnam -
> encrypted password file routines
>  …
> **shadow-utils 4.12.3**

---

The man-page I refer to here-above is part of the `shadow-utils` package and should be installed by the package manager as `/usr/share/man/man3/shadow.3.gz` irrespective of the availability of the `man` command.
Therefore one should be able to retrieve the version info from this file using zgrep :

```
zgrep 'shadow-utils' /usr/share/man/man3/shadow.3.gz
```

Full credits to [Edgar Magallon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/414186/edgar-magallon)

Comment: I updated the question, my bad I forgot to mention it I am doing this on a fresh docker image, without the `man` command installed. How do I do it within the container, not installing anything?

Comment: @linux.manifest If your package installed the manual files too then you can get the version by using something like: `zgrep 'shadow-utils' /usr/share/man/man5/shadow.5.gz` or `zgrep 'shadow-utils' /usr/share/man/man3/shadow.3.gz`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon thanks, this worked, nice solution.

Comment: @linux.manifest you can accept the answer. Hopefully MC68020 edits the answer to provide what I used (I can edit it but I prefer MC68020 does it)

Comment: Thanks @EdgarMagallon, I edited my answer in order to include your clever workaround :-)